# show that $f(z) = \dfrac{1}{π} \dfrac{c}{c^2 + z^2}$ with $0 < a < c$ decays moderately

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $S_a = \{z ∈ \mathbb{C} : |\operatorname{Im}(z)| < a\}$. An function $f(z)$ moderate decay if 
there exists a constant $A > 0$ such that

$|f(x + iy)| ≤ \dfrac{A}{1 + x^2}$     (*)

for all $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$ and $|y| < a$.

I'm trying to show that
$f(z) = \dfrac{1}{π} \dfrac{c}{c^2 + z^2}$ with $0 < a < c$ decays moderately, but I can not leave this equation as the equation (*). Can you give me a tip?

Comment: $f(z)= \dfrac{\frac{1}{\pi c^2}}{1+\frac{z^2}{c^2}}$?

Comment: @stevengregory the problem is that $|f(x+iy)|=\left| \dfrac{ \dfrac{1}{\pi c^2} }{1+\dfrac{(x+iy)^2}{c^2}} \right|=\left| \dfrac{ \dfrac{1}{\pi c^2} }{1+\dfrac{(x^2-y^2+2xyi)}{c^2}} \right|$ I do not know what to do from here.I already tried using that $\left| ||x||-||y|| \right| \leq ||x-y||$ but apparently does not help